# Particles don't behave like rigid bodies

Tags: particles, physics

How can I make particles act like little rigid bodies? I've done it before, just forgotten how. Right now, they fall right through my floor object, and into the abyss. Note, they are effected by forces, which is good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set anything you want the particles to interact with as a collision object.

Comment: derp. ty m8. i feel stupid now

Comment: Everyone forgets something sometime! ;p